# Unix MQ command usage?

Tags: ibm-mq

I've inherited a legacy system, part of which reads messages from MQ on a Unix box (SunOS 5.10 Generic_142901-13)

The following is executed via a shell script:

```
$HOME/bin/mq -g1 -dN -q $QUEUE -m $QUEUE_MANAGER $HOME/bin/out/output.xml
```

Note: At this stage I'm assuming that "mq" is a provided binary i.e. not written in house.

Question: what is this mq command that is being executed? Is it an IBM thing?
Question: where can I find docs on it?
Question: what do "-g1", "-dN" indicate?

Edit:

```
bash-3.2$ file ./mq
./mq: ELF 32-bit LSB executable 80386 Version 1, dynamically linked, not stripped, no debugging information available
```

Comment: What does `file $HOME/bin/mq` say? It might be script calling some other command (since it seems a bit unusual for a product binary to be under $HOME somewhere).

Comment: @Christian.K see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah....

```
bash-3.2$ less mq
"mq" may be a binary file.  See it anyway?
```

When I view the binary I see in side some docs!!! I've included them here for the next schmuck:

```
Copyright (C) 2007
Computer Sciences Corporation
All rights reserved.
^@^@^@usage:    mq -p[iaBDc] [-P#] [-dc] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [E#] [-S# [-w#]] [T#]\
           [-r[RQNAME]] [-R+options+RQNAME] [-xXQNAME] [-o[filename]]\
           [filenames]
        mq -g[#BDc] [-I#] [-L#] [-r#] [-dc] [-t] [-w#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR]\
           [-xXQNAME] [-s[dirspec]|filename]
        mq -b[#BDf] [-I#] [-L#] [-dc] [-w#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]\
           [-s[dirspec]|filename]
        mq -b[#BDi] [-I#] [-L#] [-dc] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]\
           [-s[dirspec]|filename]
        mq -e[#riBD] process [-I#] [-L#] [-w#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]\
           [-t] [-s[dirspec]|filename]
        mq -n [-Dw#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]
        mq -C[#Dc] [-I#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]
        PUTs, GETs, BROWSEs, processes, and clears MQSeries(R) messages
        *** WARNING: do not use a single instance of this utility to
                     put messages over a long period of time.  Because
                     it is tied up trying to read a message, it can't
                     sense that the Queue Manager is quiescing, so the
                     Queue Manager cannot be stopped normally!
        notes:  - if filename is not specified, stdin is used as input,
                  or stdout is used for output
                - errors are written to stderr
                  they can be appended '2>> file.log' for logging
                - errors can also be written to MQ_EXCEPT if this is desired
                - multiple GET or Browse messages will each be ended by line:
                  ======= end of message =======
                  unless -d is specified
^@^@            - maximum message size is %d bytes
^@^@^@^@        Common options:
          -D   prints out debug info at every step.
          -h   prints this usage statement.
          -mQM set the name of the queue manager to QM.
          -qQ  set the name of the put, get, browse, or inquire queue to Q.
          -v   prints version number of this utility to stdout.
          -xQ  puts error messages into queue Q.
        PUT:
          syntax:
            mq -p[iaBDc] [-dc] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-P#] [E#] [-S[#] [-w#]]\
               [T#] [-r[RQNAME]] [-R+options+RQNAME] [-xXQNAME]\
               [-o[filename]] [filenames]
          options:
            -p   PUT a message from stdin|filename to MQ_PUT
                 PUT multiple messages if -d is specified and -S is not.
              a  asks for message input, doesn't work with -S or -o options.
              B  binary PUT, the message descriptor Format is set to MQFMT_NONE.
              c  commit after each each message put.  If messages are being
                 split then each message segment put is committed individually.
                 Committing split messages violates the transactional nature of
                 MQSeries, so use it only when extremely large messages are
                 being split.
              dc defines the delimiter 'c' which separates messages in an
                 input stream:
                 'n' which is translated to newline,
                 'f' which is translated to formfeed,
                 and any other character is used directly as the delimiter.
                 The delimiter is not included as a part of a message.
                 If the -S and/or -o options are used, then this option defines
                 the delimiter on which the message is segmented.  In this case
                 the delimiter is included as a part of the message and is the
                 last character in each message segment.  A newline is the
                 delimiter for a split non-binary message.
              E# message expires in # seconds, default is unlimited.
                 when expiry is set, messages are set to be NOT PERSISTENT.
              I# PUT message(s) with message id = #.
              i  prints message id number to stdout after a successful put.
              o  the dequeued file will have the same name as the enqueued file
                 see option oF just below for mechanism details.
              oF specifies the name of the file (F) into which the message
                 is dequeued from the receiving queue. This option causes two
                 or more messages to be sent, the first includes the name of the
                 file, the remaining messages are the contents of a split
                 message.  Only relatively defined subdirectories are allowed,
                 no decending (../) subdirectories are allowed.
              P# sets the message priority (# in 0-9), default priority is 5.
                 The defalut priority for a split message is 1, each message
                 segment of a split message has a priority one less than
                 the first segment of a split message.
              R+ requests a report to be sent to MQ_REPLY or RQNAME if
                   specified.
                 reports can be a combination of:
                   EXCEPTION                 exception report
                   EXCEPTION_WITH_DATA         with 100 bytes of msg
                   EXCEPTION_WITH_FULL_DATA    with original msg
                   EXPIRATION                message has expired
                   EXPIRATION_WITH_DATA        with 100 bytes of msg
                   EXPIRATION_WITH_FULL_DATA   with original msg
                   COA                       confirmation of arrival
                   COA_WITH_DATA               with 100 bytes of msg
                   COA_WITH_FULL_DATA          with original msg
                   COD                       confirmation of delivery
                   COD_WITH_DATA               with 100 bytes of msg
                   COD_WITH_FULL_DATA          with original msg
                   NEW_MSG_ID                report gets a new MsgId (default)
                   PASS_MSG_ID               report gets MsgId of msg
                   COPY_MSG_ID_TO_CORREL_ID  report gets CorrelId from MsgId
                   PASS_CORREL_ID            report gets CorrelId from msg
                   DEAD_LETTER_Q             on error send original msg to DLQ
                   DISCARD_MSG               on error discard the original msg
                 example: -R+COA+COD+EXCEPTION+QNAME_OF_REPLY_QUEUE
              rQ PUT a REQUEST to MQ_REQUEST, expect reply on MQ_REPLY
                 or Q if r is followed by a Q name.
              S# splits a very large message into ~1Meg segments and puts each
                 message segment as a separate message.  # specifies the record
                 size if you have fixed length records. If record size is
                 specified then messages will be split on a multiple of the
                 record size.  If a delimiter is specified, then messages will
                 be split just after a delimiter.  If no delimiter is specified,
                 no record size is specified, and the message is not binary
                 then the message will be split after newlines.  If the message
                 is binary and no record length is specified then the message
                 will be split at 1Meg intervals.  You are not allowed to
                 specify both a delimiter and a record size.
                 The default priority of a split message is 0.
              T# sets the message descriptor MsgType to #,
                 this is ignored when a -r (request) is specified.
              w# is used to throttle putting extremely large messages,
                 it limits the flow to a 1Meg message every # seconds
                 for a maximum of 60 seconds.
        GET:
          syntax:
            mq -g[#BDc] [-I#] [-L#] [-r#] [-dc] [-t] [-w#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR]\
               [-xXQNAME] [-s[dirspec]|filename]
          options:
            -g   GET message(s) from MQ_GET, print to filename|stdout.
              #  GET # messages from MQ_GET then quit.
              B  binary GET, no character conversion is done.
              c  commit after each each message received.
              dc defines the delimiter 'c' placed between incoming messages:
                 'n' which is translated to newline,
                 'f' which is translated to formfeed,
                 'N' is translated to no delimiter between incoming messages,
                 and any other character is used directly as the delimiter.
              I# GET message(s) with message id = #.
              L# GET exactly # bytes, space fill if the message is shorter
                 than # bytes, otherwise truncate it.
                 -L0dN (displaying zero length with no delimiters) is a good
                        way to delete messages on a queue.
              r# GET only one REPLY message from MQ_REPLY whose
                 correlation id is #, if # is not specified then
                 the correlation id is read from stdin.
              s  saves the message in a file whose name is the UTC date in
                 usecs, followed by .MsgType if the MsgType is not a SYSTEM
                 MsgType.  dirspec is an optional directory specification
                 it must be adjacent to -s, not a separate argument
              t  use MQSeries' trigger data to determine GET queue
                 failed operations with a triggered queue disables
                 triggering of that queue.
              w# set GET wait interval for GET to # seconds.
                 -w10  will cause mq to wait for 10 seconds for more messages,
                 -w-10 will cause mq to wait forever for incoming messages but
                       check every 10 seconds for a ^C interrupt.
        BROWSE:
          syntax:
            mq -b[#BDf] [-I#] [-L#] [-dc] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]\
               [-s[dirspec]|filename]
          options:
            -b   browse message(s) from MQ_BROWSE, print to filename|stdout,
                 browsing only looks at a snapshot of what is in the queue,
                 it is not designed to wait for more incoming messages.
              #  browse # messages from MQ_BROWSE then quit.
              B  binary BROWSE, no character conversion is done.
              dc defines the delimiter 'c' placed between incoming messages:
                 'n' which is translated to newline,
                 'f' which is translated to formfeed,
                 'N' is translated to no delimiter between incoming messages,
                 and any other character is used directly as the delimiter.
              f  force a raw browse, split messages may not be displayed
                 in order.
              I# browse message(s) with message id = #.
              i  print MQSeries header information, not the message.
              L# browse exactly # bytes, space fill if the message is shorter
                 than # bytes, otherwise truncate it.
              s  saves the message in a file whose name is the UTC date in
                 usecs, followed by .MsgType if the MsgType is not a SYSTEM
                 MsgType.  dirspec is an optional directory specification
                 it must be adjacent to -s, not a separate argument.
        PROCESS:
          syntax:
            mq -e[#riBD] process [-I#] [-L#] [-w#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR]\
               [-xXQNAME] [-t] [-s[dirspec]|filename]
          options:
            -e   GET message(s) from MQ_GET, process them by executing the
                 process specified in the following command line argument.
                 The process is executed once for each message.
                 If a -s[dirspec] or filename is specified, the message is
                 saved to a file, and the process is called, otherwise the
                 process must accept the message from stdin, the message is
                 dequeued only if the process exits normally.  The following
                 special characters in the process string will be replaced:
                   # in the process string will be replaced by the incoming
                     message's message id
                   = in the process string will be replaced by the incoming
                     message's correlation id
                   ~ in the process string will be replaced by the incoming
                     message's MsgType
                   @ in the process string will be replaced by the filename
                     if -oFILENAME was specified when the file was put,
                     or if the -s[dirspec] or filename is specified on the
                        command line.
              #  quit after processing # messages.
              B  binary GET, no character conversion is done.
              I# process message(s) with message id = #.
              i  print reply message id number to stdout (for logging).
              r  send executed process's stdout to the GET message's
                 ReplyToQmgr:ReplyToQ, process *must NOT* redirect to stdout.
              t  use MQSeries' trigger data to determine GET queue
                 process *must NOT* have a visible pipe (|).
                 failed operations with a triggered queue disables
                 triggering of that queue.
              w# set GET wait interval for GET to # seconds.
                 -w10  will cause mq to wait for 10 seconds for more messages,
                 -w-10 will cause mq to wait forever for incoming messages but
                       check every 10 seconds for a ^C interrupt.
        INQUIRE:
          syntax:
            mq -n [-D] [-w#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]
          options:
            -n   print number of messages on MQ_INQUIRE to stdout.
              w# will cause the -n to repeat every # seconds
                 output will be qmgr(if known),queue,UTC,curdepth
                 this will continue until the process is killed.
        CLEAR:
          syntax:
            mq -C[#Dc] [-I#] [-qQNAME] [-mQMGR] [-xXQNAME]
          options:
            -C   clear # message(s) from MQ_GET
              #  the number of messages to clear from the queue, if # is not
                 specified, then all of the messages are cleared.
              c  commits each message cleared, this can take a while, but
                 may have to be done if many messages need to be cleared
                 and you don't want to take the time to clear in lots of #.
              I# clear message(s) with message id = #.
        Environment variables:
            export MQ_QMGR=queue_manager_name
              the queue manager must be specified if it is not the default
              queue manager.
            export MQ_PUT=put_to_queue_name
            export MQ_GET=get_from_queue_name
            export MQ_BROWSE=browse_from_queue_name
            export MQ_REQUEST=request_to_queue_name
            export MQ_REPLY=get_reply_from_queue_name
            export MQ_INQUIRE=inquire_of_queue_name
            export MQ_EXCEPT=report_exception_to_queue_name
        MQSeries is a registered trade mark of the IBM Corporation.
```

Closing ticket